# Subset of a normal space

Tags: general-topology

Given X a normal space, and a subset $A \subset X$ not closed. Does it imply A is not normal?

I understand it does not, Can someone provide me a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Metrizability is a hereditary property that implies normality, so every subset of a metric space is normal. In particular, $(0,1)$ is a non-closed subset of the normal space $\Bbb R$ that is itself also normal. Linearly ordered spaces with the order topology are also hereditarily normal.

However, a non-closed subset of a normal space need not be normal: normality is not a hereditary property. The [Tikhonov plank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank) $X=(\omega_1+1)\times(\omega+1)$, for instance, is a compact Hausdorff space, so it’s normal, but its subspace $X\setminus\{\langle\omega_1,\omega\rangle\}$ is not normal.